# How to stretch img element to take the full height of its div

Tags: css

I have 2 divs include different aspect ratio images. I need image2 to fill its div (container2) so both of them will be having the same height responsively.

I tried to set object-fit but it doesn't work. I do not want to set explicit height to the img element as this will not make the design flexible. I try this in order to be able to make a gallery of images all have the same height regardless what the aspect ratio is.

```css
.container-of-containers {
  display: flex;
}

.container1 {
  border: 2px red solid;
  width: 300px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.container2 {
  border: 2px red solid;
  width: 40%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class=container-of-containers>
    <div class="container1">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502307100811-6bdc0981a85b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=626&q=80" alt="" class="image1">
    </div>
    <div class="container2">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823__340.jpg" alt="" class="image2">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

So, any idea of how to make these divs have the same height without explicitly setting it on the img element?

Comment: `.container2 img { height: 100% }` use this.

Comment: yes it works this way. However, the issue persists if I remove the flex effect and align the 2 divs horizontally using floats. what is the difference? @piyushjain

Comment: `display: flex` will make both container's height equal.

Comment: @piyushjain  that's correct, thank you. It seems this is going to work only with flex or grid cause these methods by default stretches the height of their items to the height of the largest one. if you know how to fix the issue while using only floats?

Comment: rather than using <img>, why can't you show image as background? So a background-size: cover can give you awesome alignment.

Comment: @PonsPurushothaman it would be much better if I could use the background-size property, however, these images are part of the content and should be handled using <img>.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in wrapping the img in 2 divs. set the img element to absolute position. set the first div parent to relative position and padding-top to the desired percentage that would keep the wanted aspect ratio according to https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp. Set the second div parent to the desired width and float it to the left.

The code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Setting the same height on 2 different aspect ratio images </title>
  <style>

    .aspect-ratio-outer {
      width: 50%;     /* Any width here applicable according to the design */
      float: left;    /* to align the containers of the images horizontally */
    }

    .aspect-ratio-inner{ 
      padding-top: 56.25%;  /* 19:6 aspect ratio */
      position: relative;   /* to allow absolute position for the child img */
    }

    img {
      width: 100%;   /* in order not to go out of its container */
      display: block;
      object-fit: cover;  /* to keep the aspect ratio of the source image not the aspect ratio we design here */
      height: 100%;    /* in order to fill its container height which is the padding-top we set */
    }

    .aspect-ratio-inner .image {
      position: absolute;  /* To make it always appear in its container */
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="aspect-ratio-outer">
      <div class="container1 aspect-ratio-inner">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1502307100811-6bdc0981a85b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=626&q=80" alt="" class="image">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="aspect-ratio-outer">
      <div class="container2 aspect-ratio-inner">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823__340.jpg" alt="" class="image">
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```